# Configure Spring security for Ldap connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, adam

I have to configure Spring security to authenticate user through LDAP.
This is the subtree where manager user is:

```
ldaps://vldp.floal:636/CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local
```

and this is where users are:

```
ldaps://vldp.floal:636/CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local
```

So I use this setting:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
     auth.ldapAuthentication()
      .contextSource()
        .url("ldaps://vldp.floal:636/DC=fg,DC=local")
        .managerDn("CN=A0XXX32,CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local")
        .managerPassword(password)
      .and()         
      .userSearchBase("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam")     
      .userSearchFilter("(CN={0})")
      .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(myAuthPopulator);     
}
```

The problem is exception thrown when I try to make login through user, i receive this error:

```
2016-03-25 14:43:14 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name 'cn=F67XXX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam'
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:207) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name 'cn=F67XXX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:183) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BindAuthenticator.java:148) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:189) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3160) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1329) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BindAuthenticator.java:124) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

There is a problem with spring parameters because if I use java code to authenticate users it works.
I can't figure out where is the problem, can you help me?

I went in debug and this is the output before the error:

```
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: F67XXX7A
2016-03-30 11:35:22 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - Searching for user 'F67XXX7A', with user search [ searchFilter: '(CN={0})', searchBase: 'CN=fdam', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://vldp.floal:636/dc=fg,dc=local'
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Searching for entry under DN 'dc=fg,dc=local', base = 'cn=fdam', filter = '(CN={0})'
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Found DN: CN=F67XX7A,CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as cn=F67XX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - Removing pooling flag for user cn=F67XX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://vldp.floal:636/dc=fg,dc=local'
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Retrieving attributes...
2016-03-30 11:35:23 [http-nio-8086-exec-6] ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
```

PS: If with a ldap browser use `CN=F67XXX7A,CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local` it binds.

**UPDATE**: if I use java without Spring login works, I need to use Spring and figure out how to configure it:

```
@Override
public void isAuthenticated(String username, String password) throws LdapException{
    if (databaseMatlabClientServices.getByUsersEnabled(username)== null)
        throw new LdapException("User doesn't exist into DART database. Please contact the administrator!");
    String dn="";;
    //First query to retriev DN
    Hashtable<String, Object> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_URL));
//Without authentication        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
    //With authentication to access to LDAP server
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_NAME));
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_PASSWORD));
    String[] returnAttribute = {"dn"};
    DirContext ctx = null;
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setReturningAttributes(returnAttribute);
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
// without authentication on local server String filter = "uid=" + username ;
        String filter = "CN=" + username ;
        results = ctx.search(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_USERSEARCHBASE), filter, controls);
        if (results.hasMore())
            dn = results.nextElement().getNameInNamespace();
        else 
            throw new LdapException("Wrong username. Please retry!");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new LdapException(e);
    } finally {
        try{
            if (results != null)
                results.close();             
            if (ctx != null) 
                ctx.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new LdapException(e);
        }
    }

    //Second query to try to access with obtained Dn and given password
    Hashtable<String, Object> authEnv = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_URL));
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    DirContext ctx2 = null;
    try {
        ctx2 = new InitialDirContext(authEnv);
    } catch (AuthenticationException authEx) {
        throw new LdapException("Authentication error. Password was wrong");
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new LdapException(e);
    }finally {
        try{         
            if (ctx2 != null) 
                ctx2.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new LdapException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE @pczeus code***:
To set referral=follow I have used this code:

```
DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldaps://vldp.floal:636/");
contextSource.setUserDn("CN=A0XXX32,CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local");
contextSource.setPassword(password);
contextSource.setReferral("follow"); 
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();

ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
    .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(myAuthPopulator)
    .userSearchFilter("(CN={0},CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local)")
    .userSearchBase("")
    .contextSource(contextSource);
```

and I receive the classic exception:

```
2016-04-07 09:34:41 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
 ]; remaining name '/'
```

if I add `.userSearchBase("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fgadam,DC=fg,DC=local")`
I receive

```
2016-04-07 10:32:56 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - Searching for user 'F6XXX7A', with user search [ searchFilter: '(CN={0},CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local)', searchBase: 'CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2016-04-07 10:32:57 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://vldp.floal:636/'
2016-04-07 10:32:57 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local', filter = '(CN={0},CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local)'
2016-04-07 10:32:57 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

where DN is '', why?

Comment: Hmm, you have "cn=F67XXX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam", shouldn't the first element be maybe uid=F67XXX7A,...?  I'm not used to 3 cn values...

Comment: I copied it from Ldap browser I use to search and test the Ldap connection and with java code it works, it's Spring the problem

Comment: PartialResultException can be the reason of such behavior. In this case, please try to set refferal property to "follow" on Your context source. contextSource.setReferral("follow");

Comment: It seems that You have entered the hostname incorectly : floal:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: floal]

Comment: it's right because If I remove CN=ProxyUsers I can access with CN=A0XXX32 credential, furthermore I have tried with ip address receiving the same error.

Comment: Have You tried to comment the line  .userSearchBase("") ? If You don't supply it, the search will be performed on the full tree

Comment: My working configuration of the context source with Your config data is following: I have url parameter which is obvious, base:DC=fg,DC=local  userDn:CN=F67XXX7A,CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam password:YourPassword, referral:"follow" -> working as a charm.

Comment: so the url has to be only ldaps://vldp.floal:636/ otherwise doesn't work even with Ldap browser, so the error is remaning name '/' also with the above configuration, also without userSearchBase

Comment: I add userSearchBade but I retrieve bad credential, I can not explain why doesn't work for cn=ProxyUsers subtree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108488/discussion-between-maciej-czarnecki-and-luca).

Answer (score 11):

> In AbstractContextSource (parent of LdapContextSource), the Javadoc for the setBase() method says the following:
>   "Set the base suffix from which all operations should origin. If a base suffix is set, you will not have to (and, indeed, must not) specify the full distinguished names in any operations performed.".
>   Since you specify the full DN for the userDN/filter, hence you must not specify the base.

Try setting the `userSearchBase` either to an empty String (""), or remove the call all togehter.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
     auth.ldapAuthentication()
         .contextSource()
         .url("ldaps://vldp.floal:636/DC=fg,DC=local")
         .managerDn("CN=A0XXX32,CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local")
         .managerPassword(password)
         .and()         
         .userSearchBase("")     
         .userSearchFilter("CN={0},CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local")
         .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(myAuthPopulator);     
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `contextSource.setReferral("follow")` as suggested by @Maciej Czarnecki ?

Comment: you can see the error with referral in UPDATE @pczeus code in my main post

Answer (score 1):

We have a legacy app that uses Spring Security 3.2.5. We still use XML to config it. Maybe my config could help you to identify whats going on with yours.

What I noticed is that your `userSearchBase` does not use the complete "FQDN". Try using `userSearchBase("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local")` (despite the log msg "*Attempting to bind as cn=F67XX7A,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local*").

Another hint is to use a [LDAP browser tool](http://ldaptool.sourceforge.net/) in order navigate into the ldap server and check to see if the CN, DN and OU are ok.

```
<ldap-server 
         url="ldap://SERVERNAME.XPTO.BLAH:389" 
         manager-dn="usrLogin" 
         manager-password="usrPwd" />

<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider 
       role-prefix="" 
       user-search base="OU=BR,OU=MYCOMP,DC=XPTO,DC=BLAH"
       user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}" 
       group-search-base="OU=Groups,OU=BR,OU=MYCOMP,DC=XPTO,DC=BLAH"
       group-search-filter="member={0}" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapEnv" class="java.util.Hashtable" scope="prototype">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
                <beans:entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
                <beans:entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://SERVERNAME.XPTO.BLAH:389" />
                <beans:entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
                <beans:entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="usrLogin" />
                <beans:entry key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="usrPwd" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I use userSearchBase("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local" I receive the same error, furthermore now I can't use my manager credential to login to my web portal because it isn't in  ProxyUsers