# Spring security binding doens't work but search find user

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jakarta-ee, ldap

I've closed my old post to ask a more specific question. I'm using Spring security to authenticate user through LDAP and database where I have user's roles. I spent several days trying to find out where is the problem, but I still have no solution.
I have this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myAuthPopulator")
    LdapAuthoritiesPopulator myAuthPopulator;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldaps://vdap.fg.loal:636/");
        //contextSource.setBase("DC=fg,DC=local");
        contextSource.setReferral("follow"); 
        contextSource.setUserDn("CN=A0XXX32,CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local");
        contextSource.setPassword("password!");
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();

        ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
        .contextSource(contextSource)
        .userSearchBase("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local")
        .userSearchFilter("CN={0}")
        .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(myAuthPopulator);     
    }
}
```

I'm using remote Ldap to authenticate user and database to load roles, but Spring has several problem retrieving user in `CN=ProxyUsers`.
I get roles with this class

```
@Service("myAuthPopulator")
public class MyAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthoritiesPopulator.class);

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        try{
            com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(username);
            if (user==null){
                LOG.error("Threw exception in MyAuthoritiesPopulator::getGrantedAuthorities : User doesn't exist into DART database" );
            }
            else{
                //Use this if a user can have different roles
//              for(Role role : user.getRole()) {
//                  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
//              }
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getRole()));
                return authorities;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error("Threw exception in MyAuthoritiesPopulator::getGrantedAuthorities : " + ErrorExceptionBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e)); }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

This is the debug result:

```
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: F64XXXB
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch - Searching for user 'F64XXXB', with user search [ searchFilter: 'CN={0}', searchBase: 'CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://vdap.fg.loal:636/'
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local', filter = 'CN={0}'
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Found DN: CN=F64XXXB,CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local
2016-04-26 15:09:12 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as cn=F64XXXB,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://vdap.fg.loal:636/'
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - Retrieving attributes...
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name 'cn=F64XXXB,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local'
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:208) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name 'cn=F64XXXB,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local'
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:183) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BindAuthenticator.java:148) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:189) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3160) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1329) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BindAuthenticator.java:124) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local'
 ]; remaining name 'cn=F64XXXB,cn=ProxyUsers,cn=fdam,dc=fg,dc=local'
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@2026fdaa
2016-04-26 15:09:13 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /login?error
```

For test purpose I have created a class

```
@Configuration 
public class LdapConfiguration { 

    @Bean 
    public LdapContextSource contextSource () { 
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource(); 
        contextSource.setUrl("ldaps://vdap.fg.loal:636/"); 
        contextSource.setBase("DC=fg,DC=local"); 
        contextSource.setReferral("follow"); 
        contextSource.setUserDn("CN=A0XXX32,CN=Administration,CN=fdam,DC=fg,DC=local"); 
        contextSource.setPassword("password!"); 

        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet(); 

        return contextSource; 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "ldapTemplate") 
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() { 
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource()); 
    } 
}
```

and a test web service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/test/{commonName}/{password}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Response appBufferSearch(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String commonName, @PathVariable String password){ 
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter(); 
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("CN", commonName)); 
        boolean isAuthenticated = ldapTemplate.authenticate("CN=ProxyUsers,CN=fdam", filter.encode(), password);
        return new Response(true, true, isAuthenticated, null);
    }
```

and it finds my user into LDAP server without any problems, so the problem is in my `configureGlobal`, do you know why? How can I fix it?Thanks
I thought that the problem is the binding and only search works fine, this because with my manager user I can't bind other user. Maybe is this the problem?