# Using LDAP template to find certificate

Tags: active-directory, ldap, certificate, spring-ldap

Our organization stores signing certificates in Active Directory. We are using anonymous bind to search for them at a base DN (e.g. OU=MY ORG,dc=mydc,dc=org). I have been trying to use the Spring LdapTemplate to look them up, but no matter what method I use, I get the cryptic InterruptedNamingException.

Assuming a cert subject of cn=mycert.myorg.com

My code looks like this

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setUrl(String.format(LDAP_URL_FORMAT, ldapCertStoreParameters.getServerName(),
                ldapCertStoreParameters.getPort()));
contextSource.setBase(ldapCertStoreParameters.getBaseDn());
contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

X500Principal principal = x509CertSelector.getSubject();
Object obj = ldapTemplate.lookup(new LdapName(principal.getName()));
```

The X500 principal's name is the whole dn. cn=mycert.myorg.com,OU=MY ORG,dc=mydc,dc=org

I have also tried the search using just the cn.

We have verified that the DN exists on the server using Apache Directory Studio.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please remove the call altogether or set the **‘userSearchBase’** either to an empty String (“”) as per the given example in the below community thread: -

[Configure Spring security for Ldap connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305360/configure-spring-security-for-ldap-connection)

As in the **‘AbstractContextSource’**, set the base suffix from which all operations should origin. If a base suffix is set, you will not have to (and, indeed, must not) specify the full distinguished names in any operations performed. Since you specified the full DN for the userDN/filter, you must not specify the base.

AD servers are apparently unable to handle referrals automatically, which causes a **‘PartialResultException’** to be thrown whenever a referral is encountered in a search. To avoid this, set the **‘ignorePartialResultException’** property to true. There is currently no way of manually handling these referrals in the form of **‘ReferralException’**, i.e., either you get the exception (and your results are lost) or all referrals are ignored (if the server is unable to handle them properly). Neither is there any simple way to get notified that a **‘PartialResultException’** has been ignored.

For more details regarding the LDAP template search for Active Directory stored certificates, kindly refer to the link below: -

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html

•   Also, please try to refer to the below documentation for configuration of Springboot LDAP template configuration through certificates stored in Active Directory: -

https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security